# is there a standard template for a website proposal

Tags: website-design, pricing, cost

i am putting together a website for someone and i wanted to see if there is a standard template to use that includes:

- pricing (by hour, page or project)
- expected bug fixes
- costs for hosting and support
- additional maintenance.

i want to avoid missing some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a [look at the proposals that are out there](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=website%20proposal%20templa&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=website%20proposal%20template) and see what they all have in common. That would be the basis for your template. Then you can add and remove sections based on each specific proposal.

Comment: Whomever downvoted care to explain why?

Comment: Seems like a fair answer to me John. You suggested looking at existing resources on the web and tailoring it to their needs. Beyond actually writting it for them I can't see what you could have done better so a +1